# Firebase Blocking Cloud Function not returning custom error message when registering user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement user registration with email verification in Unity using Firebase Authentication and Cloud Functions. According to the Firebase documentation, I should be able to reject an user logging in using a blocking function. It is working, but it is not giving me back the right error. I have the following Cloud Function code:

```
exports.beforeSignIn = functions.auth.user().beforeSignIn((user, context) => {
  if (user.email && !user.emailVerified) {
    throw new functions.auth.HttpsError(
      'invalid-argument', `"${user.email}" needs to be verified before access is granted.`);
  }
});
```

My unity code:

```
auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
  if (task.IsCanceled || task.IsFaulted)
  {
    Debug.LogError("Failed to register user: " + task.Exception);
    foreach(Exception exc in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
    {
      Debug.Log(exc);
    }
    onFailure?.Invoke();
    return;
  }
  // Successful registration code here...
});
```

Since to my knowledge there is no way using the sdk to register an user without logging him, I wanted to catch this error and send the verification email using this error as trigger, so the email would be sent one time. But for some reason I'm not receiving the expected error.

This is what I'm receiving
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nBNf.png

Before jumping to create a custom cloud function to handle the whole registration, I wanted to ask you if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Your Cloud Function handler (the callback you passed to `beforeSignIn`) is missing the `async` keyword. Without it, your callback is throwing an exception that is not being wrapped into a Promise that the Cloud Functions Invoker can handle.

When any exception is thrown on the invoker's main thread in a deployed Cloud Function, that instance will be destroyed and a generic "An internal error has occurred" returned to the caller of the function.

If you look at the logs of your Cloud Function in the Firebase Console or Google Cloud Console, you'll see the exception being thrown there and the message that the instance of that function is being destroyed.